# JAX-WS client-side Java Soap send a Jav List of the client to the server (lack of generation in list.add JAXB)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have my Soap service sending the following values:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id","name","address", "telephones", "telephone2", "durations", "langage"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    public UUID id;
    //public List<UUID> listId;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DurationAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="duration")
    private java.time.Duration durations;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="telephones", nillable=true)
    @XmlElement(name="telephone", required=true, type=Telephone.class)
    public List<Telephone> telephones;


    private Telephone telephone2;
    private Langage langage;

//Getter setter
```

example XML :
`S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getPersonsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soa.jaxwslabs.notebookwebserviceexercice6">
         <return>
            <name>Mickael Baron</name>
            <address>Migne-Auxances</address>
            <telephones>
               <telephone>
                  <codeCountry>+1</codeCountry>
                  <codeRegional>514</codeRegional>
                  <number>571-1289</number>
               </telephone>
               <telephone>
                  <codeCountry>+213</codeCountry>
                  <codeRegional>514</codeRegional>
                  <number>999-2609</number>
               </telephone>
               <telephone>
                  <codeCountry>+33</codeCountry>
                  <codeRegional>489</codeRegional>
                  <number>777-8888</number>
               </telephone>
            </telephones>
            <duration>PT2S</duration>
            <langage>JAVA</langage>
         </return>
....`

in the code I want to add Phones (List ) has the Person object, but my newPerson.setTelephones (.....); takes a set JAXBElement  ??? so I do not voice how her my setter List ?

More information :
in jax-ws customer when my POJO class are generated (with the wsdl definition of my server service) I have the definition of the Person class that is in this form:

```
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected String address;

/* ******* */
    @XmlElementRef(name = "telephones", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<Person.Telephones> telephones;
/* ******* */

    protected Telephone telephone2;
    protected String duration;
    protected Langage langage;

....

    /**
     * Gets the value of the telephones property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Person.Telephones }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public JAXBElement<Person.Telephones> getTelephones() {
        return telephones;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the telephones property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Person.Telephones }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public void setTelephones(JAXBElement<Person.Telephones> value) {
        this.telephones = value;
    }

...
//Setter getter
```

It does not therefore allow me at do:

`telephone = new Telephone();
telephone.setCodeCountry("+1"); telephone.setCodeRegional("514"); telephone.setNumber("989-2789");
telephones.add(telephone);`

The objects are not the same as my POJO dimension Jax-ws server. So as I bit beyond the generation problems of the List  ?? (Automatically generated JAXB I think that causes problems)

Comment: Has the `Telephone` class the tag `@XmlRootElement` ? Try also to define `telephone`s as `private` and include a setter and getter. Move also the annotations `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement(name = "telephone")` to getter method. Sometimes it fails

Comment: I Error  message : 'There are two properties named \"telephones\"  this problem is related to the following location: at public java.util.ArrayList soa.jaxwslabs.notebookwebserviceexercice6.Person.getTelephones() at private soa.jaxwslabs.notebookwebserviceexercice6.Person soa.jaxwslabs.notebookwebserviceexercice6.jaxws_asm.GetPersonAtResponse._return'

Comment: Use `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement` only on getter. Set variable `telephones` as private. With `XmlAccessType.FIELD` JAXB will map annotated properties and fields